# Is it possible to write nested format strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting, string-formatting

I want to write something like

```
format_specifier = "{some_dict[some_key]}"
```

to later use it together with `.format()`:

```
result = format_specifier.format(some_dict={"one": "eins", "two": "zwei"}, some_key="one")
```

which I wanted to evaluate to `"eins"`, but instead I get a `KeyError`:

```
KeyError: 'some_key'
```

I also tried extra braces: `"{some_dict[{some_key}]}"` resulting in `KeyError: '{some_key}'`..

Is nesting format strings like this possible in the first place?

*Note: I have to evaluate the string later so I guess f-string formatting is not an option for me..*

Answer (score 1):

If you use `eval` and define your used format arguments as a collection of local variables you can evaluate the format string.

```
format_specifier = "some_dict[another_dict[some_key]]"

def formatComplex(str, **kwargs):
  # check str for correct format: only regex [a-zA-Z0-9\[\]] allowed
  return eval(str, None, kwargs)

result = formatComplex(format_specifier, some_dict={3:"Hello"}, another_dict={"bla":3}, some_key="bla")

print (result)
```

You can add this to your string formatting by writing your own `string.Formatter` sub class and implement a new `parse()` method that substitutes these complex formats into literal text

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8) I now do it like this, but I think it can be simplified very much if not Python has a built-in method to do this:

```
def formatComplex(specifier: str, format_data):
    result = specifier
    while True:
        matches = re.findall(".*{([A-Za-z0-9_\-\/\ \,\.\'\"\(\)\[\]]+)}.*", result)
        if not matches:
            break
        for m in matches:
            result = result.replace("{%s}" % m, str(eval(m, None, format_data)))
            
    return result
```

```
>>> format_specifier = "{some_dict[another_dict[some_key]]} world"
>>> formatComplex(format_specifier, {
...    "some_dict": {3: "Hello"}, 
...    "another_dict": "three": 3}, 
...    "some_key":"three"})
Hello world
```

```
>>> formatComplex("Hello {who} {what} bar", {"who": "world", "what": "foo"})
Hello world foo bar
```